# Troubleshooting JVM Jar opening

Tags: java, jvm, classpath, classloading

I have a tiny Java program "Test.java", which relies on a class "TestLib" found in a separate jar file in the same directory.

"Project" Structure:

```
$ ls
Test.java   Test.class   testlib.jar
```

Test.java and testlib.jar are stub artifacts that reproduces a classpath problem I'm seeing in a much largert application.  All Test.java does is instantiate a class from testlib.jar, and exit:

```
import com.TestLib;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Before instantiating testlib");
        new TestLib();
        System.out.println("After instantiating testlib");
    }
}
```

My test jar has the test library class in question:

```
$ unzip -l testlib.jar
...
com/TestLib.class
...
```

(The jar contains many other classes and meta-inf files, omitted here)

I can compile this little project with: `javac Test.java -classpath .:testlib.jar`

I attempt to run it with the command `java -classpath .:testlib.jar Test`, and get the output:

```
Before instantiating testlib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/TestLib at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

It can't find "TestLib"!

Interestingly when I add the `-verbose` flag to my java invocation, I can see that it never even opens my library jar to look for TestLib there:

```
$ java -verbose -classpath .:testlib.jar Test 2>&1 | grep "Opened"
[Opened /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Opened /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar]
[Opened /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar]
```

What determines whether the JVM opens a jar file to look for a missing class?  Are there any META-INF or other jar contents that prevent a jar from being opened by the JVM?  What steps should I take to troubleshoot why "TestLib" is not found at runtime?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you? With exactly this code, and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was seeing this behavior because of a `META-INF/INDEX.LIST` file present in my JAR.

That file (when present) contains a list of class files available in the JAR.  My INDEX.LIST file was incomplete, and didn't mention my `TestLib` class.  So when ClassLoaders came looking, they believed the list of jar contents in `INDEX.LIST`, and reported that they couldn't find the class.

(I ended up with an incomplete `INDEX.LIST` because of some unconventional (read, incorrect) usage of Gradle's "shadow" plugin.  By default the shadow plugin removes any INDEX.LIST files when building the shaded jar, but I'd accidentally configured it to not do this.  So if you're seeing this behavior in a shaded jar, this is likely the cause.)